# XSLT transform only displaying 1st match

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I'm new to xsl and am trying to transform a soap response into simple html using an xslt. My desired result should display the children of each siteSummaryList node in a paragraph list. My problem is that the output displays only the first match (TEST SITE 1 in the example below). Curiously it displays it twice indicating that it does find the second match but displays the 1st data again. Can anyone see or explain what I am doing incorrectly?

Thanks

XML

```
<ns:getSitesResponse xmlns:ns="http://scada.api.web.companyx">
<ns:return 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:ax226="http://scada.response.entity.web.companyx/xsd" xsi:type="ax226:SiteSummaryResponse">

<ax226:siteSummaryList xsi:type="ax226:SiteSummary">
<ax226:alarmCount>8</ax226:alarmCount>
<ax226:label>TEST SITE 1</ax226:label>
<ax226:typeLabel>TYPE 1</ax226:typeLabel>
</ax226:siteSummaryList>

<ax226:siteSummaryList xsi:type="ax226:SiteSummary">
<ax226:alarmCount>6</ax226:alarmCount>
<ax226:label>TEST SITE 2</ax226:label>
<ax226:typeLabel>TYPE 2</ax226:typeLabel>
</ax226:siteSummaryList>
</ns:return>
</ns:getSitesResponse>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:p="http://scada.response.entity.web.companyx/xsd" exclude-result-prefixes="p">

<xsl:output method="html" indent="no" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//p:siteSummaryList" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//p:siteSummaryList">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="//p:label" /></p>
        <p><xsl:value-of select="//p:typeLabel" /></p>
        <p><xsl:value-of select="//p:alarmCount" /></p>         
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//p:label" />
```

to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="p:label" />
```

The expression `//p:label` selects all `p:label` nodes in the entire document, starting from the root node - and (in XSLT 1.0) `xsl:value-of` returns the string value of the **first** one of these.

Note also that starting a *match pattern* with a `//` is redundant.